# SQL query - Cumulatively concatenate strings in consecutive rows

Tags: sql

I'm a data analyst, so I write SQL queries to retrieve data from a database. I'm not sure what kind of SQL exactly, just assume the most standard (also not things like 'DECLARE @tbl', and no create functions etc.)

Here is my problem.
Given the following table:

| name | number | letter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | a |
| A | 2 | b |
| A | 3 | c |
| A | 4 | d |
| B | 1 | a |
| B | 2 | b |
| B | 3 | c |
| B | 4 | d |

I want the following result: (concatenate letter cumulatively, order by number))

| name | number | letter | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | a | a |
| A | 2 | b | a,b |
| A | 3 | c | a,b,c |
| A | 4 | d | a,b,c,d |
| B | 1 | a | a |
| B | 2 | b | a,b |
| B | 3 | c | a,b,c |
| B | 4 | d | a,b,c,d |

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question which was tagged MySQL.

MySQL doesn't support `group_concat()` as a window function.  So a subquery may be your best alternative:

```
select t.*,
       (select group_concat(t2.letter order by t2.number)
        from t t2
        where t2.name = t.name and t2.number <= t.number
       ) as letters
from t;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the function group_concat() isn't registered on my data platform...

Comment: @Jason . . . Your question is tagged "mysql" and this is a MySQL answer.

Comment: I see, my bad. Will remove the tag.

Comment: @Jason: so which DBMS product **do** you use?